# sql server 2008 stored procedure multiple selects in mybatis

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, mybatis, mssql-jdbc

I have a problem about stored procedure multiple selects in mybatis.

Two select statements in stored_procedure.sql

```
USE cellar;
GO
alter PROCEDURE findAll_sp
AS
SELECT * FROM wine ORDER BY name;  //The results of this select statement are stored in the list.
SELECT * FROM wine where id=5;  //The results of this select statement are not stored in the list.
GO
```

stored_procedure.sql

Only one select statement's result(first select sentence) in the stored_procedure.sql is saved in a list of WineDAO.java. But I want to be on the list of all the two select statement's result.
How can I solve this problem?

The following is the relevant source code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="org.coenraets.cellar.cellar-mapper"> 
    <select id="findAll" resultType="Wine"> 
        {call findALL_sp}
    </select>
</mapper>
```

mapper.xml

```
public class WineDAO {

    private static SqlSessionFactory ssf;

    static{ 
        try{
            Reader reader= org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources.getResourceAsReader("Config.xml");
            ssf=new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);
        }catch(Exception ex){ex.getMessage();}
    }

    public List<Wine> findAll() {
        List<Wine> list = new ArrayList<Wine>();
        list = ssf.openSession().selectList("findAll");

        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(list.get(i).getName());
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

WineDAO.java

Thank you.

Comment: As it is a stored procedure you are executing two statements, the result of your procedure will be the last one, you can't retrieve both. Either use a UNION on your query of separate the two statements in different queries (different mybatis statements).  Something like `SELECT * FROM wine ORDER BY name UNION SELECT * FROM wine where id=5`

Comment: " you can't retrieve both" - not true. Lookup MARS

Comment: Thank you for answer, Jorge. Many Stored Procedure already have a multiple select sentence in my project. So there is no other way in mybatis, I'm going to give up mybatis. Thanks again.

Comment: MARS? What is the MARS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="org.coenraets.cellar.cellar-mapper"> 

     <resultMap id="WineAll" type="Wine">    
        <id property="id" column="id"/>
        <result property="name" column="name"/>
        <result property="grapes" column="grapes"/>
        <result property="country" column="country"/>
        <result property="region" column="region"/>
        <result property="year" column="year"/>
        <result property="picture" column="picture"/>
        <result property="description" column="description"/>   
     </resultMap>

     <resultMap id="WineFive" type="Wine">
        <id property="id" column="id"/>
        <result property="name" column="name"/>
        <result property="grapes" column="grapes"/>
        <result property="country" column="country"/>
        <result property="region" column="region"/>
        <result property="year" column="year"/>
        <result property="picture" column="picture"/>
        <result property="description" column="description"/>   
     </resultMap>


     <select id="findAll" resultMap="WineAll, WineFive"> 
          {call findALL_sp}
     </select>

</mapper>
```

mapper.xml

```
public class WineDAO {

    private static SqlSessionFactory ssf;

    static{ 
        try{
            Reader reader= org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources.getResourceAsReader("Config.xml");
            ssf=new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);
        }catch(Exception ex){ex.getMessage();}
    }

    public List<Wine> findAll() {

        List<List<Wine>>list = new ArrayList<List<Wine>>();

        list = ssf.openSession().selectList("findAll");

        for(int i=0; i<list.get(0).size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(list.get(0).get(i).getName());
        }

        return list.get(0);
    }
}
```

WineDAO.java

list.get(0) -> SELECT * FROM wine ORDER BY name;

list.get(1) -> SELECT * FROM wine WHERE id=5;

```
public class Wine {

    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String grapes;

    private String country;

    private String region;

    private String year;

    private String picture;

    private String description;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGrapes() {
        return grapes;
    }

    public void setGrapes(String grapes) {
        this.grapes = grapes;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getRegion() {
        return region;
    }

    public void setRegion(String region) {
        this.region = region;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getPicture() {
        return picture;
    }

    public void setPicture(String picture) {
        this.picture = picture;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Wine.java

I solved the problem by using the resultmap. Thank you :)